# How to clean up after subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen, lsof

I have a long-running python script with a perl worker subprocess.  Data is sent in and out of the child proc through its stdin and stdout. Periodically, the child must be restarted.

Unfortunately, after a while of running, it runs out of files ('too many open files').  lsof shows many remaining open pipes.

What's the proper way to clean up after a Popen'd process?  Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
def start_helper(self):
    # spawn perl helper
    cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    if not cwd:
        cwd = '.'

    self.subp = subprocess.Popen(['perl', 'theperlthing.pl'], shell=False, cwd=cwd,
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 bufsize=1, env=perl_env)

def restart_helper(self):
    # clean up
    if self.subp.stdin:
        self.subp.stdin.close()
    if self.subp.stdout:
        self.subp.stdout.close()
    if self.subp.stderr:
        self.subp.stderr.close()

    # kill
    try:
        self.subp.kill()
    except OSError:
        # can't kill a dead proc
        pass
    self.subp.wait() # ?

    self.start_helper()
```

Comment: `Popen.kill` (or `Popen.terminate`) is your best bet.

Comment: When you kill it, could it be raising an OSError for any reason other than already being dead?

Comment: here's a somewhat unrelated bug in `subprocess` but it could shed some light on `_cleanup()` http://bugs.python.org/issue1731717

Comment: use `close_fds=True` (default on py3k) if you're not on Windows

Comment: btw, on some systems there is a ridiculously small limit on number of open files.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, I've added close_fds and will see, but it looks like that cleans up the fds from the master proc in the child, not vice-versa?

Comment: @dkuebric: I don't know.

Comment: Have you tried checking what's on the other end of those open pipes?  Here's an unsophisticated hack which relies on NODE being the 8th field of lsof output:  `lsof | grep " \($(lsof -p YOUR_PYTHON_PID | grep pipe | awk '{if (FNR > 1) {printf "%s", "\\|"} printf "%s", $8}')\) "`  If the other ends are your perl processes, then you have a leak somehow...

Comment: I hate to say it, but I really want to know why the perl script has to periodically be killed and restarted in the first place!

Comment: So the python process is running out of open file descriptors?  Are you running the child perl process multiple times in the parent?  It's not clear why the parent process would be using additional file descriptors from this example.

Comment: Which version of Python and which OS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that's all you need:

```
def restart_helper(self):
    # kill the process if open
    try:
        self.subp.kill()
    except OSError:
        # can't kill a dead proc
        pass

    self.start_helper()
    # the wait comes after you opened the process
    # if you want to know how the process ended you can add
    # > if self.subp.wait() != 0:
    # usually a process that exits with 0 had no errors
    self.subp.wait()
```

As far as I know all file objects will be closed before the popen process gets killed.

Comment: The wait() is the key to not leaving subprocesses and open pipes behind.

Comment: I think this ended up being true.

Answer (score 1):

A quick experiment shows that `x = open("/etc/motd"); x = 1` cleans up after itself and leaves no open file descriptor.  If you drop the last reference to a `subprocess.Popen` the pipes seem to stick around.  Is it possible you are re-invoking `start_helper()` (or even some other `Popen`) without explicitly closing and stopping the old one?